# BigQuery and Google analytics compatibility issues

Tags: google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I’d like to create conversion funnels with events. Most of the events I created are listed under “Select_content”. However, Google Analytics does not allow me to choose any of the specific events under “Select_content”, only the whole category of “Select_content”. Is there any way that I can create a conversion funnel using the specific events under “Select_content”?

Is there any way to break out the `CONTACT_DETAIL` event into its specific events (e.g. `CALL`, `MESSAGE`, `TAG`, `DATE`, etc.)?

This is how I send Google Analytics event from iOS app

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSelectContent, parameters: [
   AnalyticsParameterItemID: "id-\(id)" as NSObject,
   AnalyticsParameterItemName: itemName as NSObject,
   AnalyticsParameterContentType: contentType as NSObject
])
```

What's wrong with it? Why is BigQuery not able to go in to deeper level from already uploaded Google Analytics data?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you have setup your events you access them via the `EventCategory`, `EventAction` or `EventLabel` and all of these get passed into BigQuery assuming you have connected your Google Analytics data import.

[image]

If, for example, the events you are looking for have the Event Category of `Select_content` then you can start by filtering just these events with a WHERE clause such as:
`WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "Select_content"`

Note that in order to get to the `.hits` level in the nested data you will need to `UNNEST` hits, for example like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(hits.eventinfo.eventlabel) AS my_events, 
FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between 
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 7 day) and
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)
AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "Ecommerce"
```

You could also add to the WHERE clause to filter into a specific Event Action, if you don't want to see everything that's under the Event Category, for example:

```
WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "Ecommerce"
AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "Purchase"
```

Once you have managed to isolate the correct events for your funnel it should be pretty straightforward to assemble a funnel from the counts.

Hope that helps!